# What semantical versioning says when there are braking changes to introduce but a major version was already introduced in the past?

Tags: git, semantic-versioning

I create a software with semantical versioning.

```
[1.0.0]<--[1.0.1]
```

At some point, I need to introduce some breaking changes. I decide to add branch 2.0 and maintain also 1.0.

```
[1.0.0]<--[1.0.1]<--[2.0.0]<--[2.0.1]
```

And the development continue.

```
                   /-[2.0.0]<--[2.0.1]<--[2.0.2]
                   |
[1.0.0]<--[1.0.1]<--[1.0.2]
```

Now I need to introduce new features in 1.0, so I decide to start branch 1.1.

```
                   /-[2.0.0]<--[2.0.1]<--[2.0.2]
                   |
                   |         /-[1.1.0]<--[1.1.1]<--[1.1.2]
                   |         |
[1.0.0]<--[1.0.1]<--[1.0.2]<--[1.0.3]
```

Now, ... Now I need to introduce BC in version 1.1 but verision 2.0 already exists. Semantical versioning says to increment major version. But What if major version were incremented in the past? Is the time for version 3.0? Are 3.0 and 2.0 divergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making breaking changes you must increment the major version. Nothing in the [SemVer spec](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/418) requires that increment to be exactly 1. If you have a situation where a set of BC's must be applied to a maintenance fork, rather than the head of the product line, you probably actually have two products in mind and should simply create a new one with its own version track. The spec does not require 3.x.x be related to 2.x.x and 1.x.x, but it is unusual for the lineage not to hold.

In the case of product forks (branches), you can also take the track of versioning each branch independently of the other, but you must not ever release more than one Prod.x.y.z, so you essentially are releasing two products; perhaps Prod.B1.x.y.z and Prod.B2.x.y.z.